# Subdomain Cookie

Tags: magento2, cookie, multi-website

I have a problem with my subdomain in Magento 2.1.6.

The user session is not kept between websites.

My websites are like this:

- sub1.market.com
- sub2.market.com
- www.market.com

I set the cookie subdomain like this: `.market.com`

But the session is not kept, I tried to log in www.market.com and when I go to sub1.market.com I am not connected.

I already cleared the cache, flushed the cache, and reindexed. I also cleared the browser cookies. I tried `market.com` as cookie and `/` as cookie path and nothing worked.

I need to do this it's a major task, but i'm out of idea. If someone can helpme!

- Magento 2.1.6
- Dev on localhost using wamp
- Php 7
- change localhost with custom link (www.market.com)

In a previous install it was working, but with this install it don't want to work.

**EDIT** : I already searched, but every problems is about the multi websites without using `www.` so cookie domain is not kept. In my case I set a `www.` domain and try every cookie domain.

**EDIT 2 22.06.2017**
My cookie pathis empty and my cookie domain is `market-eurecia.com` But when I go to the cookie with chrome, the path is `/` and the domain is `.market.com`

Comment: Is the cookie set in the browser when you log in for the correct domain (i.e. .market.com)?

Comment: When I go to `chrome://settings/cookies` there is 4 cookie on market.com
PHPSESSID, admin, admin, formkey. The PHPSESSID have `path: /`, `domain : .market.com`. Also there is noSID in url i have only the sub1.market.com.

Answer (score 0):

I find it !

It was the ... Store - Config - Customer  Account sharing from Websites to Global ^_^

I forget there was this option ..